# What is the highest magnitude of destruction practical for a WMD?

Tags: environment, science-fiction, weapon-mass-destruction

**For my new short story, I was thinking about future weapon technologies, and there is one thing that does not leave me rest:**

I can think about (*SF-class, like anti-matter guns, space distortion bombs etc.*) weapon technologies that would be capable of destroying an entire planet (or even a solar system), but *what for*? I mean the point of *real war*s was never the destruction, but to establish power over the enemy. Pure destruction is pointless and the destruction caused by the wars is almost always considered like casual damage, or a necessary evil of the situation. Now my question is about the magnitude of destruction a weapon can cause which still worth's to be applied (let's say in mega tonnes and environmental load)?

**Criteria:**

- *Blowing up (or rendering uninhabitable) the whole world (planet) is a **big no**!* The sides are fighting against each other but they are fighting **over something**, and that something has to remain intact.
- *Blowing the planet out of its course is out of question.* Remember, it has to stay habitable!
- *I am curious about conventional weapon tech in the sort of it is blowing up, evaporating or burning stuff.* There are means to get rid of the enemy without destruction, but I'm simply not asking about those ways. *To put it simple; what I'm curious about is big bombs.*
- Think about warfaring continents or so! *Think huge.*

Comment: Basically you are asking how far one would go in using a WMD? Generally the idea is "as far as we need to, and if we go down you are coming with us". To so-and-so hidden under a mountain might no be important if creating a disaster on the surface will destroy everything, but since you say that "*that something* has to remain intact" the limit would be exactly that: as long as *that something* is safe the rest can all go... which can go in any direction depending on what "*that something*" is. And remember that plenty of wars have been fought just to obliterate the other party

Comment: Since the end of (and even during) the Cold War, there has been a transition from simply making bigger bombs to creating smaller, more tactical ones. One of the realities of attempting to apply nuclear weapons to warfare _without_ triggering MAD is that you need to be able to more precisely control what does and doesn’t get damaged. Bigger bombs aren’t practical unless you’re engaged in Total War and need to destroy cities (in which case you get MAD).

Comment: The largest amount of destruction that is reasonable depends on the size of the thing you are at war with. Taking out a whole planet can be fine if you're fighting an empire spanning dozens or hundreds of them.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Let's just assume, generals of this war are people of habits and they got used to see the sun and drink natural water that doesn't come from a recycling system. :-)

Comment: The question asks how big of a boom can we make, but the criteria state otherwise.

Comment: At what scale is your war? It is local? Nation-wide? Continental? Intercontinental? Global? Planetary (planet vs satellites)? Interplanetary? Interstellar? Gallactic? And so on... I think this must be clarified due to some answers stating an space war while your question seems more like you are asking about a more conventional non-space war. Or maybe I misinterpret your question. You know, I can get one of my planets vaporized as long as I own dozens, but If you drop a nuke over Monaco an entire country would be deleted.

Comment: Seems a bit opinion based. Fundamentally, 'practical' is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: There's a host of assumptions that a responder must make about the objectives and circumstances surrounding this situation.  Without greater clarity on these aims and circumstances, the question is just too broad.

Comment: @Green I think I have defined what I'm asking for quite clearly.

Comment: @mg30rg haven't you watched Star Wars?  "*Think huge*" is about as contradictory with "*Think about warfaring continents or so!*" as we can imagine.  Also, making an area uninhabitable **is** a valid strategy if your purpose is to **terrorize other** groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different assumptions that need to be made before we can answer the question of what is the most powerful weapon that could be effectively used without rendering a planet inhabitable.

First, we need to assume we are using a 'clean' sci-fi method of destruction - we don't need to worry about high levels of radiation from the fallout that results from a detonation.  This may be moot as modern thermonuclear weapons tend to become cleaner as their yield increases but I'm not sure just how that would scale.

Second, we need to assume we're talking about some form of an explosive weapon.  Chemical weapons, biological weapons, etc are out of the scope of the discussion.  This would be a nuke, anti-matter bomb, ultra-high velocity kinetic weapon, or something similar.

Third, we're talking about a single weapon rather than the deployment of a number of smaller individual weapons.  There are a number of reasons to use many smaller weapons in this case - it's a fine line to walk between destroying everything but still leaving at least a good portion of it habitable.

The destruction of an explosive weapon doesn't scale linearly with yield due to the inverse square law, and because planets are spherical no matter where you detonate the weapon half of it will be in shadow.  Most of the explosive force of an incredibly large bomb will radiate into space as well.

That said, I would imagine a weapon in the range of ten gigatons (200 Tsar Bombas) would be destructive enough to devastate all but hardened shelters across a planet the size of earth.  Between the fireball itself and the radiation / thermal pulse, most everything that had line of sight to the explosion would be completely annihilated.

The rest of the planet would fare better, but the thermal and sonic effects - along with the weather systems that would probably result - would be pretty devastating as well.  Still, once things settled down after a few days, the area outside the immediate vicinity of the detonation should be livable again.

Comment: "*200 Tsar Bombas would be destructive enough to devastate all but hardened shelters across a planet the size of earth.*"  **Hogwash.** Tsar Bomba came nowhere near to wiping out 1/2 of 1% of the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

" There are levels of survival we are prepared to accept." Architect (Matrix Reloaded)

If you are fighting an interstellar war and 90% of the enemies production is coming from the Sol system, but it is only one of a dozen systems you want, destroying the Sol system to win the war could be a reasonable loss.

If you are fighting a interplanetary war within the Sol system, and your freedom is at risk you might be willing to threaten the entire earth with destruction so that your Europa colony, or Planet X colony can be free. Once you've threatened, its a small step to launching that planet killing asteroid.

I am sure if you went back to the american revolution and asked everyone, there would be some that would gladly have let everyone in England die to ensure their freedom. It's just a matter of weather someone that extreme managed to get in charge.

Some wars are fought for ideas and ideals. Freedom, religion, ect.

**Tera forming**

So what if earths atmosphere is ruined? If you have tera forming tech you can always rebuild it later. In your own image.

**Someone wants all the buildings saved**

Massive cobalt radiation bombs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_bomb

The radiation kills everyone but leave the infrastructure intact. Within 6 months radiation levels drop to human tolerable levels. Resistance fighters could survive this, especially with advanced shielding.

This could be scaled up to make a star send out a radiation burst to do this to everything in a system.

**Death Star**

Is the leader bent on galactic conquest? Literally blowing up a planet death-star like is not only intact, but highly useful (And practical). All those resources you would have had to mine miles into a planets crust, and then launch into orbit are floating about as asteroids and easy to capture and refine. Heck, the planet is even more habitable since you could create so many more space habitats out of those resources then could live on the surface of such a planet.

Comment: Nice one, but doesn't answers my question. Take a peek at the criteria again.

Comment: It rely hinges on what the leader views as intact. Does the leader have tera forming technology? Then having a complete biosphere wiped out is "intact".

Comment: Is the leader bent on galactic conquest? Literally blowing up a planet death-star like is not only intact, but highly useful. All those resources you would have had to mine miles into a planets crust, and then launch into orbit are floating about as asteroids and easy to capture and refine. Heck, the planet is even more habitable since you could create so many more space habitats out of those resources then could live on the surface of such a planet.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the highest magnitude of destruction practical for a WMD?

As high as you want it. The real question is: what happens next? Because if your enemy can retaliate, they will.

All nuclear powers have a "don't launch nukes first" policy, as well as an "appropriate response/non-escalation" policy. You only throw what your opponent throws at you. If you are receiving bad words, then don't escalate to missiles. Because soon enough you escalate to the top of scale and that's bad for everybody.

I'd like to come back on the "don't launch nukes first" policy. The keyword is *launch*. You don't have to wait until nukes are falling on your head to retaliate. It's what's considered a preemptive strike, i.e. striking before you get hit, *not* before you are attacked (as some misinterpret it). So consider that the retaliation might come sooner than you expected.

The general idea is to not start a war you cannot finish.

---

Now about the kind of WMD you could use, there are the obvious nukes. A big H-bomb on the capital city should be a good first strike, but there's something better you could do with it though.

Nuclear weapons have 4 effects: blast, heat, ionizing radiations and electromagnetic radiations. With the last one alone, a nuclear weapon detonated in high-altitude could disable electronics in most of the US + Canada. [Experiments on the subject proved rather conclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfish_Prime). For a society that relies on computers for just about everything, that's one critical blow.

In the WMD category you also have biochemical weapons. Be warned, those might come back to bite you in the arse big time. On the scale of morality, biochemical weapons are way past the event horizon, and in my personal opinion can be far worst than nukes. I wouldn't use those under any circumstances, because they are by far to most unpredictable.

Leaving the WMD realm but close enough are [thermobaric weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermobaric_weapon). From the Greek thermos (heat) and baros (pressure). Those are biggest non-nuclear weapons we have and would be quite destructive if dropped in the middle of a city.

But who need weapons when you have computers, right? [Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_cyberattacks_on_Estonia) [proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberattacks_during_the_Russo-Georgian_War), [allegedly](http://www.wsj.com/articles/ukraine-cyberwars-hottest-front-1447121671), that a computer can be quite disruptive. So maybe it's not as flashy as bombs, but a war of attrition from the comfort of your living room is an option to consider. When their economy has crashed and people are rioting in the streets, then you swoop in and finish them off. Note however that if their economy is linked to yours, you might feel it as well.

This isn't a very sci-fi-y list by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If your civilization spans multiple planets, then you may be at a smaller risk of [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction). In that case, you drop asteroids from orbit and devastate entire countries as needed. The yield of these explosions is almost entirely up to you. The yield of the asteroid that impacted the Yucatan peninsula is measured in *millions* of megatons, so you could potentially get some impressive fireballs without devastating the entire planet beyond habitation.

If your civilization only has a single planet (as today), then MAD immediately applies. Even if you’re the only one with this powerful new weapon, multiple nations have hydrogen bombs capable of dealing very significant damage to you.

**A Big Bomb**

If all you want is a big bomb and damn the consequences, then look at the [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba). It was a 50 megaton detonation that could have potentially been increased up to 100 megatons. If you want to just keep going bigger you might be able to squeeze out a few more megatons, but there comes a point where the weapon is too unwieldy to be used effectively.

**MAD**

That’s all well and good, but the core of your question asks about the magnitude of a weapon that’s *still worth being used*. In the real world, MAD is a serious concept that must be averted at all costs. If your weapon leads to a chain reaction that renders the world unlivable, you’ve violated your requirements. This means that dropping the Tsar Bomba on Moscow or New York City is a big no-no. But what else would you use it on? When you reach that level of destruction collateral damage is unavoidable.

Instead, you go tactical. Indeed, this has been the trend since the Cold War: smaller bombs that can be efficiently used *against enemy combatants*. If you want to avoid MAD, you must operate tactically and not target cities full of civilians. [Modern tactical nuclear weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_nuclear_weapon) can range from anywhere between 1 and 100 kilotons (some even being adjustable depending on the situation). For comparison, the bombs dropped on Hiroshima and Nagasaki were between 15 and 20 kilotons. In today’s modern world, a nation *might* be able to get away with using a tactical nuclear weapon against a force of purely enemy combatants. This type of usage would cause enormous international outrage, but probably would not trigger MAD. What it would do is usher in a disturbing new era of offensive nuclear weapon capability.

As a result, your most practical yield is probably somewhere in the 1 to 25 kiloton range.